# How to append value using math.round in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have this line of code Input and Output format

- Input : 0%   Output: 0%
- Input :100 % Output : 100%
- Input :65.23% Output : 65%

but I am always getting **NAN** Please help me.

```js
$("#NameMatchSummary").each(function() {
  var namematch = $(this).find('.divNameMatch').length;
  for (var o = 1; o <= namematch; o++) {
    var namevalue = 0%100%65.23%;
    var splitvalue = namevalue.split('%');
    //var nameMatchT = Math.round(splitvalue);
    var nameMatchT = Math.round(Number(splitvalue[o]));
    //alert(nameMatchT);
    $('#spnNameMatch' + o).text(nameMatchT + "%");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NameMatchSummary" class="pad1x flex-col-xs-3 flex-col-sm-6 DataSourceEnqInfo">
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">
    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch1">NaN%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">

    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch2">NaN%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">
    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch3">NaN%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet so it reproduces your problem.

Comment: Click "Run code snippet".

Comment: Tried Not working @HereticMonkey

Comment: That's the point. You have to fix your errors.

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/q1z5h67g/2](JS Fiddle) Please check this.And check line number 9 in javascript code.

Comment: Change your latest edit to `var namevalue = "0%100%65.23%";`

Comment: yes @freedomn-m

Comment: Also, please don't edit the *question* to try to resolve it based on (bad) answers.

Comment: "yes"? what does that mean?  There's nothing wrong with your (current) snippet when you provide a valid input (put the string in quotes).  And your fiddle /2 also works fine without giving NaN.   What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Your original code should have been `splitvalue[0]` instead of `splitvalue[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `string` value to `number`

Replace

```
var nameMatchT = Math.round(splitvalue[i]);
```

With

```
var nameMatchT = Math.round(Number(splitvalue[0]));
```

```js
$("#NameMatchSummary").each(function() {
  var namematch = $(this).find('.divNameMatch').length;
  for (var o = 1; o <= namematch; o++) {debugger;
    var namevalue = $('#spnNameMatch' + o).text();
    var splitvalue = namevalue.split('%');
    //var nameMatchT = Math.round(splitvalue);
    var nameMatchT = Math.round(Number(splitvalue[0]));
    //alert(nameMatchT);
    $('#spnNameMatch' + o).text(nameMatchT + "%");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NameMatchSummary" class="pad1x flex-col-xs-3 flex-col-sm-6 DataSourceEnqInfo">
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">
    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch1">0%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">

    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch2">100%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="divNameMatch" class="divNameMatch flex-row_left divEnqInfo">
    <div class="pad1x NameMatchiv">
      <span class="labelValue" name="spnNameMatch" id="spnNameMatch3">65.23%</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or use shorthand +splitvalue[i]

Comment: Still shows the Reference Error "i is not defined"...

Comment: This answer ignores code and context completely. Unless you try and fix this, this is nothing more than an attempt to grab easy rep.

Comment: @ChrisG turns out `Math.round(splitvalue[i])` was in the *original* code provided by OP (and should have simply been `Math.round(splitvalue[0])`, no need to convert to number first)

Comment: @Kenny in your snippet, you've changed `[i]` to `[0]` without mentioning this is the *actual* fix - adding `Number(` has no impact, so it's a little misleading.